# Is the network traffic from Hubs and Tiles encrypted?

Tags: security, cellular-data

When I use features that use data connection like "What's New" in People Hub or seeing pictures from Facebook or OneDrive on the Picture Hub, is the network traffic encrypted?

I am worried because sometimes I use open WiFi connections and I'm afraid that someone can see my data in "plain text".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you disable WiFi and connect your phone using the USB cable and open Zune, your phone should be using the internet of the computer automatically. If you now use http://www.wireshark.org/ you can see the actual traffic.

Whether a secure connection is used depends from application to application, so one could go and create a community wiki answer to list them. In any case, this is something very interesting and it might be handy to bring this to the attention of the responsible developers that their are security issues.

**Bottom line of the story:** Make sure applications only can send/receive personal data when you access those applications, don't let them do background traffic. Together with that, don't access critical personal data in public. Other than that, consider a "privacy is dead" viewpoint, because unless your a very important / valuable person there's most likely not much interest in your data.

*But, be wary of any traffic you do on WiFi networks involving hundreds of people...*

**Update: Yes**, at least the People Hub's traffic is encrypted.

Comment: Sorry. I think I don't made myself clear. I not meant applications but build-in features. My concern is about using Facebook built-in things with open WiFi and somebody stole password os something else only to bother me.

Comment: These are applications as well, you just can't uninstall them.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I've forgot this. So It depends on MSFT implementation.

Comment: Maybe the only way is to open xap ond look for.

Comment: @VitorCanova: Read my first paragraph again, no need to reverse engineer. Just monitoring is fine... :)

Comment: I tried to use this software but is very hard to me. When I use a filter by my phone's ip it did't show any traffic when access picture-hub. I tried again without filter and looks like some specific traffic appear when I access the hub. But I cannot understand the information it provides.

Comment: @VitorCanova: It's late here... But I'll see what I can do tomorrow. So, I should check out People and Pictures Hub, is there more? Note that you can do `ip.host == put.phone.ip.here` to filter it right. From there on you should look if there is HTTPS or SSL protocol stuff; tutorials might help you, note that it might be valuable for your developer career to get to know this tool if you're going into web / network programming. Especially given that you mention WCF too on your profile...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3693/discussion-between-vitor-canova-and-tom-wijsman)

Comment: @VitorCanova: The phone uses the same IP as your computer, it just routes through the traffic. So you would have to make your computer's traffic as quiet as possible. In my testing I've confirmed that the People Hub does only send encrypted traffic, I however forgot to do the Pictures Hub because I was busy (I basically planned to update the answer, but then I was distracted :(). Might or might not check later...

Comment: Great. I tought it uses the same IP it receive when via Wifi.